# Problem regarding the time of downloading and creating app in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, download, frontend, backend

I have typed out these-

```
npm -v
6.14.4
node -v
v12.17.0
npm i -g create-react-app
added a few packages
create-react-app react-app
```

Now in the directory created I have a file named react-app. This has a package.json file.
This is present in the following package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true
}
```

It has been almost six hours. There hasn't been a single file (other than package.json) been added. What changes do I need to make?. These are the lines after I enter the create react statement in command line.

```
Creating a new React app in C:\Users\<Closed>\<Closed>\react-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
```

It has the cursor in the next line and shows nothing, it keeps blinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official documentation suggests that you use npx. Try this:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

See here: https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

There is no reason why you should install create-react-app globally. (`-g`).

Also, if it takes longer than like 10minutes depending on your internet connection, stop the command since something is not working. Don't wait six hours!

Comment: it was overnight. Anyways thanks a lot. Will look into your solution and update

Comment: Do I have to uninstall anything before I do the above commands?

Comment: You can run `npm remove -g create-react-app` just to be sure it's gone. Also, make sure the folder `my-app` does not exist already. (Replace `my-app` with your app name). You can delete your previous try by doing `rm -rf my-app` which will delete the folder for you.

Comment: It did not resolve the issue. It still takes a lot of time. I am not sure if it is an internet issue or an accessiblity issue as the command prompt is not responding.

Comment: are you using any sort of VPN? Try it without. Try using your mobile phone as a hotspot if possible. All operation systems and terminals should work. If mobile internet does not solve the problem, try restarting your pc, reinstalling npm / node, using a different terminal (in that order).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. Actually I had to finally install WSL to install the stuff. Your commands worked in the ubuntu prompt. Cheers!